# Windows shortcut - relative path on removable drive

Tags: batch-file, usb-flash-drive, shortcuts, file-shortcut

bascially, there are several threads that ask more or less the same, but none seems to really answer the question for my case.

So, I have a removable drive (usb flash drive), which has one *.bat file on it. There are several shortcuts to this *.bat file. The problem: logically, the drive letter may change on another computer, which makes the shortcut non working anymore.

I can't use something like %windir%, because its on the removable drive. I also can't use another *.bat file, rather then a shortcut.

Now the question is: is there any way to have the shortcuts relative or in a way that allows it to work on any computer, that it gets plugged in into?

Comment: Why are you unable to use another bat file? If you're referring to an ever changing drive letter, some scripting (batch or other) will have to be involved. Can you maybe describe your particular case and its constraints in a bit more detail?

Comment: Because the shortcuts look much more "authentic" then a bat file.. My particular use case here is a media drop attack (baiting), where I have the shortcuts basically all have the batch file opened. The shortcuts are all tempting files to click for interested employees - all basically social engineering to see the reaction of the employees. For the shortcuts, I can easily give those tempting names and also fitting icons, which won't work for a script file of any kind...

Comment: You could drop a batch file that finds said USB drive (for example by checking if the actual bat file exists in a very specific path) on the C-drive, then place a shortcut to that?

Comment: @MiG yeah, but the employees won't have anthing on the batch file there... It can be plugged in in any random computer, so there's nothing on the computer itself and everything has to come on the usb drive...

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why shortcuts would look more *"authentic"*, can you elaborate what you mean? And shortcuts need a fixed path (unless they rely on a variable that's set on the machine, in which case you also already know what driveletter it has)... You're describing a chicken-and-egg situation, I'm not sure if there's a solution that specifically uses .lnk files rather than a .bat (or .cmd or .ps1 or other script file) extension, where the script figures out where it is (and in which case you might as well launch your payload already).

Comment: @MiG so first, the shortcuts don't need an extension. So even if user has his Windows set to display file extensions, they still won't see anything suspicious there. Also, I can use any symbol for the shortcut, like a folder symbol, or one for pdf or word doc. The only "bad" thing here is the shortcut arrow in the bottom left corner, although most users propably won't really notice that. If you have better ideas, I'm absolutely down for them, but the hard thing is to get something solidly working, but still tempting for the user to click on it..

Comment: Note that a shortcut *has* an extension, that would be .lnk. By default windows *"hides extensions for known filetypes"*, so on a stock configuration you don't see it (but the file type does really have an extension!). And my point is that what you're asking is probably not doable without calling on a script file in the first place. A shortcut can only link to a relative path (in a variable) that is already known, so you'd have to set that variable first (with a script). Hope I'm making sense.

Comment: @MiG yeah, makes sense.. I mean, in the end, if it doesn't work, it doesn't work.. Just hoped anybody has a good idea.. Do you happen to have another idea on how to get it working but still have a tempty looking file (or multiple), where most employees would click on?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following batch:

`SET "_HD=1"` used only to process the remainder of bat if not found.

---one liner to find a disk by Volume Name you assign:

```
FOR %%A IN (D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) 
DO (VOL %%A: 2>NUL | FIND "Volume Name" >NUL & IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 SET "_HD=%%A")
```

-or-

Look for the batch you want to run assumed in a fixed location everywhere:

```
IF EXIST %%A:\<path if needed>\xxx.bat SET "_HD=%%A"
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the `.bat` file *on the drive*.
The root folder is maybe the easiest to use.

Any folder referred-to inside the file should not contain any drive-letter.
The references will then be relative to the folder in which is located
the `.bat` file.

Comment: yeah, that won't work unfortunately.. both, the links and the .bat file itself has to be on the drive...

Comment: My suggestion is to put everything on the external disk. If you put an [autorun.inf](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/autorun-cmds) on the root of the disk whose `action` is to run the `.bat` file, then double-click in Explorer on the disk should run the `.bat` file (if Microsoft hasn't destroyed that option).

Comment: yeah, I think autorun won't work anymore, also that's not the primary intention, as users should click the extensions...

Comment: autorun doesn't work *automatically*, but autorun.inf probably still works if manually launched by double-click.

Comment: that might be, but at least it wouldn't help me in my specific scenario (unfortunately) - see my comments above